# Reset and clear out Shiny text output using reset button

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I am creating a calculator that takes multiple inputs and prints the calculation after clicking 'Calculate'.  I also provide a reset button that successfully resets the input values back to their default.

The reset button should also **clear the previously printed output** (basically I want it to look exactly like it did when you first open the app).

Below is a simplified and still functioning example of the calculator.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)


ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  div(id="form",
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("x","X",0),
      numericInput("y","Y",0)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      br(),
      column(width=6,actionButton("calc", "Calculate")),
      column(width=6,actionButton("reset", "Reset")), 
      br(),br(),br(),
      textOutput("sum"))
  )
))


# Define the server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$sum <- renderText({
    req(input$calc)
    isolate(paste("X + Y =", input$x + input$y))
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    reset("form")
      })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have tried a few approaches offered on here for other, seemingly similar questions but I haven't managed to get them to work.  I would offer some examples of what I've done but I've lost track of them at this point and I'm hoping there's just some obvious, simple answer that I've overlooked.  I'm fairly new to Shiny, though, so details of why a possible answer works would also be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Edited to based on comments.*

I think the simplest observer would be:

```
# two observers
server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$calc, {
    output$sum <- renderText({
      req(input$calc)
      isolate(paste("X + Y =", input$x + input$y))
    })
  })


  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    output$sum <- renderText({

    })
  })
}
```

Comment: I think the question is about deleting/resetting the printed output, not the `numericInput`.

Comment: Edited. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly!  I threw back in my line of code to reset the inputs too and that also works.  The interesting thing is that I thought I tried an approach just like this in my actual work (not just this simple example) and it crashed on me.  I'm sure it was just user error somewhere but once I see that this works I will mark it as answered.